# flutter & cloud firestore for web, ios, web

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-web

I want to develop a flutter app for android, ios and web. My idea was to use flutter so that I can build all of those three components with the same source code. As a DB I decided to use cloud firestore, as I thought that it would have the easiest flutter integration. For android it works great, however for web my code seems unusable.

I came across this plugin list, and it seems the only plugins available also for web are firebase_core and firebase_auth: 
https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire#available-flutterfire-plugins

So now I have the following questions:

1. What can I do with the firebase_core plugin? Can I access my firestore DB? (There seems to be no real documentation..)

Comment: Your second question is asking for a technology recommendation, which is off-topic on Stack Overflow. You might want to remove it to prevent your question from being closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To learn what you can do with the `firebase-core` plugin, have a look at the [sample app](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/blob/master/packages/firebase_core/firebase_core/example/lib/main.dart) for it.

Mostly it allows you to create `FirebaseApp` objects, which you need to create any of the other Firebase service objects (such as FirebaseAuth). So while you can't really do anything meaningful with just `firebase-core`, it is a prerequisite for most other Firebase services.